# Overflowing button in Xamarin Forms

Tags: layout, xamarin.forms

I've got a mockup with a screen I don't know how to implement properly:

[image]

I'm wondering how to position that Login button (and the "sign in with" block). Without "Login", it would be quite easy with a StackLayout. But this makes it less easy and I'm searching for a simple solution.

I presume it's feasible with an AbsoluteLayout with position calculations in the codebehind, but that makes the whole page more complicated than it looks.

The white block is a Frame that's used everywhere in the app. It's not specific to the login page, so I want to reuse it elsewhere.

How would you do that?

Answer (score 4):

I think you can use a Grid... with 3 rows.
Rows 1 and 2 have the same height.
"Login data" (User/pwd...) occupy row 0 and 1
Button occupy row 2 and 2

For Example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="fev_ventilazione_smartwatch.Pages.MyPageTest">
    <ContentPage.Content>

        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="8*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="4*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="4*" />
              </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Label Text="TEXT" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" BackgroundColor="Aqua"/>
            <Button Text="BUTTON" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" BackgroundColor="Fuchsia"/>
        </Grid>

    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Produce

[image: Overflowing button]

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean, how can that help me to have the button partially going off the frame?

Comment: Not sure why people are down voting this answer, although it's short; using a grid layout would still be a valid option. ( so I upvoted the answer again )

Comment: @MorganTouvereyQuilling if you put 2 controls inside a grid (same row and col), the second is "over" the first. If your first control occupy row 0 and 1 and your second control occupy row 1 and 2 (using the same column), you have 2 controls that occupy row 1 so the second is "over" the first

Comment: Ah, that's much clearer indeed. I will experiment a bit with your solution, Umair's one and maybe a RelativeLayout and accept the closest answer, but take my upvote!

Answer (score 1):

> I presume it's feasible with an AbsoluteLayout with position
>   calculations in the codebehind, but that makes the whole page more
>   complicated than it looks.

Yes you are right. It is feasible with `AbsoluteLayout`. But its not as complicated as it seems.

Construct your basic elements first:

1. White container/StackLayout for login details
2. Login Button.
3. Facebook/Google buttons in a horizontal StackLayout.
4. "OR" Label
5. "Create An Account" Button

Put them in `AbsoluteLayout` and define their `AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags` as well as `AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds`.

Now key here is to understand that **how Absolute Layout works?**

You can find that out from this page: [Absolute Layout](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/absolute-layout/)

I have wrote some code to achieve something similar below. But make sure you learn it fully and understand everything before you can use it in your app:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <ScrollView BackgroundColor="Silver">
        <AbsoluteLayout Margin="30" >
            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White" HeightRequest="150" Spacing="20" Padding="10" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,250" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="XProportional,YProportional,WidthProportional"
                >
                <Entry Text="Login" HeightRequest="30"/>
                <Entry Text="Password" HeightRequest="30" IsPassword="true" />
                <Label Text="FORGOT YOUR PASSOWORD?" HorizontalTextAlignment="End"/>
            </StackLayout>
            <Button 
                Text="LOGIN" 
                FontAttributes="Bold" 
                BackgroundColor="Maroon" 
                TextColor="White" 
                HeightRequest="70" 
                WidthRequest="70" 
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".5,215,70,70" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="XProportional" BorderRadius="35"
            />


            <StackLayout 
                Orientation="Horizontal" 
                HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,270,0.5,70" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="XProportional,WidthProportional"
            >
                <Button Text="Facebook"/>
                <Button Text="Google"/>
            </StackLayout>
            <Label Text="OR" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,350,50,50" 
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="XProportional"
            />
            <Button 
                Text="CREATE AN ACCOUNT" Margin="15"  
                BackgroundColor="White" TextColor="Maroon" 
                BorderColor="Maroon" BorderWidth="1" 
                BorderRadius="0" 
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,370,1,150" 
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="XProportional,WidthProportional"
            />
        </AbsoluteLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

And here is the result:

[image]

**NOTE:** You can achieve the same look using RelativeLayout as well.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer and having taken the time to make an example! Tried it, I will experiment a bit with a Grid and a RelativeLayout too and accept the closest answer, but you've got an upvote.

Comment: I believe that using Grid method won't be much consistent. As your control's  (login button) height depends on the shared row height. Which would be hard to manage on different screen sizes. However Absolute Layout is a correct way of doing this, also recommended by Xamarin. Cheers!